# JS call function every 5 mins count of server time

Tags: javascript, date

I need to call some JS function every 5 mins, but not simply every 5 mins after page loading, but on every 5 mins of server time. Ie when server clock reaches 5, 10, 15 etc mins.

I wrote next code, but i dont know how to calk timeout to call first function when current server time < %5 minutes (03:13:28 for example)..

First time i call function on page load, but next time it must be called on server time event.

```
Dig = new Date(parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000)*1000);
var min = Dig.getMinutes();
var sec = Dig.getSeconds();
if(min%5==0){
  var to = ((300-sec)*1000);
}else{
  // HERE MY PROBLEM
}
setTimeout(function(){
  myFunction();
  setInterval(function(){
    // do something every 5 mins on server time
    myFunction();
  }, 300000);
}, to);
```

Now i do the //PROBLEM place like

```
    var os = 0;
    if(min<4){
        os = 4-min;
    }else if(min<9){
        os = 9-min;
    }else if(min<14){
        os = 14-min;
    }else if(min<19){
        os = 19-min;
    }else if(min<24){
        os = 24-min;
    }else if(min<29){
        os = 29-min;
    }else if(min<34){
        os = 34-min;
    }else if(min<39){
        os = 35-min;
    }else if(min<44){
        os = 44-min;
    }else if(min<49){
        os = 49-min;
    }else if(min<54){
        os = 54-min;
    }else if(min<59){
        os = 59-min;
    }
    sec = 60-sec;
    os = ((os*60)+sec);
    var to = (os*1000);
```

but i need shortest variant.

Comment: you could use bidirectional connections, i.e. websockets, then you could write the timeouts server side, and send to all clients

Comment: what is on server side? Suggest to use SingalR.

Comment: i just start to learn websockets and now i need solution for js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to find out how many milliseconds it is from "now" until the next five-minute mark, here's how you do that:

```
var fiveMinutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;
var now = new Date().getTime();
var untilNextFiveMinuteMark = fiveMinutes - (now % fiveMinutes);
console.log("now is " + new Date(now));
console.log("time to next five-minute mark: " + untilNextFiveMinuteMark + "ms");
console.log("next five minute mark: " + new Date(now + untilNextFiveMinuteMark));
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/anAboQad/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/anAboQad/1/edit)

For instance, for me right now (I'm in the UK), it says:

```
now is Sun Feb 02 2014 13:47:36 GMT+0000 (GMT)
time to next five-minute mark: 143169ms
next five minute mark: Sun Feb 02 2014 13:50:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

In your question, more than once you talk about "server time," but there's nothing in your code doing anything related to the time on the server. It's all using the time on the client. To get the time on the server, you have to have the server send that information to the client and then use it (and even then, of course there will be inaccuracy, as it takes an indeterminate time for the client to retrieve the time value from the server; in normal use, that time will be small).

Comment: Thank you! You right - my code posted here not used server time, but i post it to users can check it simply with copy-paste from here to jsFiddle and write answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can show the timestamp on the page by server side language

```
<script>
var serverTimeStamp = <?php echo (1000*time());?>; 
</script>
```

and you will have a actual server time value on this particular page.

Also you can make ajax calls to server, that will return the actual server time,
and perform client site javascript actions when the time have come.

Comment: Problem not with time. Problem with getting the time offset to next 5 minutes count.

Answer (score -1):

> **Call every 5 mins on SERVER time**

I don't see major differences with every 5 mins on server time and client machine time.

> ***Every 5 minutes is always 5 minutes every where.***

There is no need to calculate 5 minutes gap, just set the interval `window.setInterval()`

### SAMPLE Code:

```
var counter = 0;
CallEvery5Minutes();

var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
    CallEvery5Minutes();
}, 5000);  //5000 is 5 Seconds

function CallEvery5Minutes() {
    console.log("5 Minutes Completed!!! = '" + counter + "'");
    if (counter == 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log("Interval has been cleared!!!");
    }

    counter += 1;
}
```

*Here `5000` is `5 Seconds`.*

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/57mbP/)**

Comment: 5 minutes is NOT true 5 minutes in my case. If i load page and use your examlpe, my function will executed every 5 seconds AFTER PAGE LOADING. But i need it to be executed just when the SERVER timer is hh:05:00, hh:10:00, hh:15:00 etc. Ie i need to get time offset to next function execution. It will be different after every page load.

Comment: @SirD: There's nothing related to server time on your code. JS should be used  mainly for client side scripts not for server side.

Comment: @SirD: If there are 5 concurrent users, how you will determine 5 mins and whom do you server the request